# AngularJS unit testing factory with sweetAlert by jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

I know that my issue is kind of easy, but I can't understand it and can't resolve it :|

It's about testing factory function, which calls sweetAlert function from http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/.

This is my factory:

```
.factory('sweetAlertService', [function(){
    return {
        /*
            Alerts: TEXT - 'content', TYPE - 'success', 'warning', 'error', 'default'
        */
        addAlert: function(text) {
            sweetAlert('', text, 'success');
        },

        addNormalAlert: function(text, something) {
            window.alert('', text, something);
        }
    };
}])
```

And this is my test:

```
describe('sweetAlertService factory', function() {
    var alertService;

    beforeEach(inject(function(sweetAlertService) {
        spyOn(sweetAlertService, 'addNormalAlert').and.callThrough();
        spyOn(sweetAlertService, 'addAlert').and.callThrough();
        alertService = sweetAlertService;
    }));

    it('it should test the normalAlert function in service', function() {
        alertService.addNormalAlert('text');
        expect(alertService.addNormalAlert).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it('it should test the addAlert function in sweetAlert service', function() {
        alertService.addAlert('text', 'success');
        expect(alertService.addAlert).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

It's strange, but I don't know why function 'addNormalAlert' pass test and function with sweetAlert function 'addAlert' doesn't.

Has anyone had a similar problem earlier? Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: I think you are missing here the inclusion of `sweetAlert` js in your test case runner.  You have used `callThrough`, which basically in addition to create spy on the defined method also makes the call to actual function, so here in your code it will try to call sweetAlert, for which you need to include `sweetAlert` library in your test case runner. Or the other way around you can simply use `spyOn(sweetAlertService, 'addAlert')` instead of `spyOn(sweetAlertService, 'addAlert').and.callThrough()`

Comment: Thank you! Without 'and.callThrough()' it's work.
But you said also that I can include library in my test case runner, how can I do it? 
I haven't found any good information about including external libraries to jasmine in google, cause I had already tried before :o

Comment: It depends on how you are executing test cases either via some test case runner like karma or simply using spec.html. 1. If you are using some test case runner then you can configure the configuration file(like "karma.conf.js") of that test case runner to use `sweetAlert` library 2. Or if you are using spec.html to run test cases, just include the reference to `sweetAlert` library in that html using `script` tag. Also please upvote the answer if it helped.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much, I use karma and I totally forget that it have to added in karma.conf.js :|

Comment: Ok. gr8. please upvote the comments if these helped.

Comment: I can't do this yet cause I'm new here, but when I get some point of reputation, going to upvote you!

Comment: Ok. Thanks!, you can do whenever u get enough reputations :)